# Parse Dashboard configuration error "Your config file contains invalid JSON. Exiting."

Tags: parse-platform, dashboard, parse-server

I am trying to install Parse Dashboard on AWS. The public directory works but the /apps directory is blank.

When looking at the logs I see

```
> parse-dashboard@1.0.14 start /var/app/current
> node ./Parse-Dashboard/index.js

Your config file contains invalid JSON. Exiting.
```

I am deploying the parse-dashboard from github. And I have entered in the values in the parse-dashboard-config.json that match the keys on parse.com.

This is the JSON that I am using

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
     "serverURL": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/parse",
     "appId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "masterKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "appName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     }
    ],
   "iconsFolder": "icons"
}
```

In index.js the log is being generated by

```
129   if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
130      console.log('Your config file contains invalid JSON. Exiting.');
131      process.exit(1);
132   }
```

Comment: Have you validated the JavaScript of "index.js", e.g. with [www.jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com/)?

Comment: It fails all over the place. So are we saying here that the parse-dashboard on github has invalid index.js file even though it runs locally?

Comment: index.js is valid, this would be the JSON file.

can you try `node ./Parse-Dashboard/index.js --config path/to/config.json`

Comment: Any answer on this one?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's looking for an answer, the `parse-dashboard-config.json` file should be in the your current folder where you're running

`parse-dashboard --config parse-dashboard-config.json`